# How to reference Arn and name of AWS lambda function created with Serverless Framework

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, serverless-framework

I am using the Serverless Framework to create a lambda function and would like to be able to cross-reference its Arn and name in other parts of serverless.yml.

I'm surprised how difficult I'm finding this as !GetAtt and !Ref do not seem to work as I would expect if the lambda was created via vanilla CloudFormation. (AWS::Lambda::Function returns Ref and Fn::GetAtt which would make this easy!)

I have found a few posts, that allude to solutions, but nothing that states in plain English how to achieve this.

### SETUP

### serverless.yml

```
...
functions:
  - ${file(functions/sendEmail.yml)}
...
```

### sendEmail.yml

```
sendEmail:
  handler: lambda-functions/send-email.handler
...
```

### ATTEMPTS TO REFERENCE

### Arn

In another part of the template I have attempted:

```
...    
LambdaFunctionArn: !GetAtt sendEmail.Arn
```

but, when I deploy, I get:

```
Error: The CloudFormation template is invalid: Template error: instance of Fn::GetAtt references undefined resource sendEmail
```

I notice that the final CloudFormation template has converted sendEmail to sendEmailLambdaFunction, so I then tried:

```
LambdaFunctionArn: !GetAtt sendEmailLambdaFunction.Arn
```

but received a similar error.

### Name

I also would like to be able to reference the name, but sadly

```
!Ref sendEmail
```

causes the error:

```
Error: The CloudFormation template is invalid: Template format error: Unresolved resource dependencies [sendEmail] in the Resources block of the template
```

Any assistance with regards to precise changes I need to make, in order to achieve grabbing the lambda's Arn and name, would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks in advance!
I

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I am not sure of the best practice, but the below works for me.

Provide functionName in the serverless function and when you want the arn, you can form it.

**test.yaml**

```
TestFunction:
  Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
  Properties:
    Handler: index.handler
    FunctionName: myFunction
```

When referencing,

```
LambdaArn: !Sub arn:aws:lambda:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:function:myFunction
```

Answer (score 6):

Ok, with thanks to [Dinush](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10248244/dinush) for putting me on track, I achieved a functional solution as follows:

### serverless.yml

```
custom:
  ...
  myEnvironment:
    assetPreName: ${self:service.name}-${self:provider.stage}
    arnRegionAndAccount: ${self:provider.region}:#{AWS::AccountId}
  ...
  myContact:
    ...
    lambdaFuncName: ${self:custom.myEnvironment.assetPreName}-sendEmail
    lambdaFuncArn: arn:aws:lambda:${self:custom.myEnvironment.arnRegionAndAccount}:function:${self:custom.myContact.lambdaFuncName}
```

**Note:** The notation:

```
#{AWS::AccountId}
```

requires the plugin: serverless-pseudo-parameters.

### sendEmail.yml

```
sendEmail:
  ...
  name: ${self:custom.myContact.lambdaFuncName}
  ...
```

### Elsewhere

```
LambdaFunctionArn: ${self:custom.myContact.lambdaFuncArn}
```

I still think it's a shame that I couldn't simply use Ref and Fn::GetAtt (as I would be able to if the lambda was created via a vanilla CloudFormation, AWS::Lambda::Function, resource), but this works for now.

Hope this helps someone else. Thanks again, [Dinush](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10248244/dinush) for setting me on this course!

Comment: This is exactly why I do not suggest using that framework, SAM is much much better.