# How to expose ARN of resource created by the Serverless Framework to Terraform

Tags: aws-lambda, terraform, serverless-framework, terraform-provider-aws, aws-serverless

We are planning to use the Serverless framework to create AWS lambda functions, and Terraform to provision other infrastructure in AWS. We use SSM parameters to get access in Serverless to resources created by Terraform.

However, I am wondering: is there any way to access in Terraform resources created by Serverless? The use case is as follows: in terraform we need to give explicit bucket permissions for a lambda created in Serverless. At the moment we need to hard code the ARN of the lambda. Is there any way to avoid that?

Comment: Similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60439849/how-to-reference-arn-and-name-of-aws-lambda-function-created-with-serverless-fra

Comment: Interesting use case. Personally, I think you should try to reduce the complexity of your deployment processes. I don't see the upside of this approach. Why not use Terraform for the Lambdas as well? I can only imagine that you like to use the ability to test/run the Lambda locally? One way to achieve something similar is to use unit tests for your Lambdas to develop/test them locally. I do this a lot and it works quite well. This way you would not need serverless anymore and can use Terraform exclusively.

Answer (score 0):

`Serverless` uses `CloudFormation` under the hood and there is no direct way to share data between `CloudFormation` and `terraform`. Most common way is to use SSM to share data in both directions, so I think you are on the right track (you can use [data source](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/data-sources/ssm_parameter) to fetch value from SSM).

There is an overview how to use `Serverless` framework with `terraform` in [this blog post](https://www.serverless.com/blog/definitive-guide-terraform-serverless)

Comment: Yes, I saw that blog but there they only talk about using resources defined in terraform in Serverless, not the other way around. I am not sure how data source will work with SSM, I need to look into that. Do you have experience doing that? Could you maybe provide an example?

Comment: If a CloudFormation stack defined by Serverless has useful outputs then it might work to read the stack's outputs directly using [`aws_cloudformation_stack`](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/data-sources/cloudformation_stack), though I'm not familiar enough with Serverless to say if the Lambda function ARN would be available there. With that said, you'd then need to write the name of the CloudFormation Stack in your Terraform config, which you might consider to be no better than writing in the Lambda function ARN.